# Jenkins slave machine Windows configuration

Tags: jenkins, tfs, configuration, msbuild, slave

I am very new to Jenkins and sort of new to build .net application, but the guy left team so I have been assigned to do this. I have read tons of articles online about setting up Jenkins master, but little about slave configuration. The guy created a new slave and connect with Jenkins master successfully before he left. And he told me that slave is responsible for 1) downloading source code from TFS server and 2) building them.

now my issue is what do I need to install in the slave machine( windows system) to be able to perform that two tasks? 
1) for downloading source code, do I need to install TFS client on slave ?
2) for building source code, do I need to install MSbuild or entire Visual studio ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you installed a recent version of the [Team Foundation Server Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin), then no TFS Client is required (see https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin#400-and-later-new).

Depending on what you are building, installing Visual Studio maybe required or not. In my experience, only a limited set of project types build with just MSBuild and without Visual Studio. There are hacks or supported tips but they work only in specific cases: YMMV.

The new [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 RC](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017-rc) are making this requirement a thing of the past: if you can migrate your code to Visual Studio 2017 you will be able to use them.

Comment: I tried immediately, and it worked! Thanks a lot! I download VS on slave machine, and MSBuild is downloaded with VS automatically. But I only use MSBuild command to build my projects. One more question,just curious about the plugin mechanism. Since plugin is installed in Jenkins master, does it mean Jenkins master downloads the source code and then transfer the source code to slave machine?  or it is some magic Jenkins software installed in slave machine does the downloading  ?